# Wordpress/PHP Warning, Creating default object, Can't access Admin Panel Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, object, header, default

This is all new for me. My wordpress website is throwing this error...

> [25-Jun-2015 11:28:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /.../public_html/chrismarsh.us/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/admin/functions.php on line 229

And unwanted ads started showing up everywhere. So I tried to log into my admin panel to see if it was a plugin problem and it throws this error...

> [25-Jun-2015 13:53:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /.../public_html/chrismarsh.us/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/admin/functions.php on line 229
>
> [25-Jun-2015 13:53:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../public_html/chrismarsh.us/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/admin/functions.php:229) in /.../public_html/chrismarsh.us/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178

Can anyone help me out? The website is chrismarsh.us

Comment: Go into functions.php and whatever variable is on line 229 add `$var = new stdClass();` before it

Comment: Thanks! Below is the code from line 217-235 with your suggestion. It now throws this error...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING) in /home4/cmarsh17/public_html/chrismarsh.us/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/admin/functions.php on line 1

Comment: Lines 217-235

// ---------------  Global Theme Options -------------------- //



$standard_options_db = get_option('standard_framework_'.STANDARD_FRAMEWORK_SHORT_NAME);

global $standard_options;

if(is_array($standard_options_db)):

    foreach ($standard_options_db as $k => $v):
  $var = new stdClass();
  $standard_options -> {$k} = $v;

    endforeach;

endif;

standard_multiple($update_option->theme1);

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your wp-config.php and your /wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/functions.php to make sure there is no whitespace before the `<?php` part of the file. I don't know why that happens but it does happen sometimes and it will throw "PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." as a result.

Not saying this is the only possible reason but it is one possible reason based on what I've encountered working with WordPress.

Comment: Thank You! I checked both and there is no whitespace. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you also checked if there is a whitespace in /wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_272/ad‌​min/functions.php as well?